# ClientWidth and ClientHeight are undefined

Tags: jquery, d3.js

I am trying to get clientWidth and clientHeight for my svg element. Based on this tutorial https://bl.ocks.org/curran/3a68b0c81991e2e94b19, I have made changes to my code like this.

```
let w = $('.graph');
let clientWidth = w.clientWidth;
let clientHeight = w.clientHeight;
console.log('CW is ' + clientWidth);
console.log('CH is ' + clientHeight);
```

When I am debugging I have a clientWidth and clientHeight value. I am not sure why I am getting a undefined value. Can somebody help me why this is happening.[Dev tools result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rv23P.png)

Comment: clientWidth and clientHeight should be 0 for SVG elements. You may be relying on a browser bug here if you're getting some other value. https://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view-1/#extension-to-the-element-interface

Comment: Besides the information Robert Longson just gave you, in the code you linked `clientWidth` and `clientHeight` refer to the `<div>`, not to the SVG.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I have appended my svg to that div with class graph!

Comment: Your question makes us think that you're selecting the SVG. Besides that, your printscreen doesn't show undefined, but two clear and nice values. So, what is undefined?

Answer (score 2):

`$('.graph')` returns a jQuery collection, which doesn't have a `clientWidth` property *or* a `clientWidth()` method.

I don't think jQuery has a method that's equivalent to `clientWidth` and `clientHeight`.  But assuming you have only one graph element, you can get these properties by accessing the DOM node directly using `[0]`:

```
let w = $('.graph')[0];  //added [0]
let clientWidth = w.clientWidth;
let clientHeight = w.clientHeight;
console.log('CW is ' + clientWidth);
console.log('CH is ' + clientHeight);
```

Comment: He's right!. .clientWidth() or .clientHeight() are not jQuery functions. You need to access the DOM directy as Rick Hitchcock said.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var a={data:'hai',value:'hi'};
function clickMe(){
alert(a.data);
}
function undifined(){
alert(a.hai)
}
```

```html
<button onClick="clickMe()">click me</button>
<button onClick="undifined()">click Me Undefined</button>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
let w = $('.graph');
let clientWidth = w.clientWidth();
let clientHeight = w.clientHeight();
console.log('CW is ' + clientWidth);
console.log('CH is ' + clientHeight);
```

Add "()" to the end of the functions (x.clientWidth(), x.clientHeight()).

Comment: I have tried this. That did not work! It throws error saying that clientWidth and clientHeight is not a function.

Comment: if it was a function that you could call, then console logging clientHeight and clientWidth would not be undefined, they would be a function

Comment: Lol what? clientHeight is not a function.

Comment: It is not a function.